# Low FPS clips too fast in VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am using the Video Sequence Editor and when I put a low FPS clip into it it is way too fast. I think that Blender is basing the speed of the clips on their framerate rather than their actual speed and length. Can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can setup FPS of the scene in render settings:

[image]

#### But if you have video files with different FPS values in one scene, you can do this:

1. Add a movie strip with different fps value:

[image]

2. Select Video (not sound) and add Speed Control effect (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> -> **Effect Strip** -> **Speed Control**)

[image]

3. By moving end of the strip adjust strip length to be equal sound strip:

[image]

4. Optionaly, you can put all this in meta-strip (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)

[image]

#### If you haven't sound strip, you can setup Speed Control this way:

1. Uncheck "Stretch to input strip length"
2. In Speed factor put `{FPS of your file}`/`{FPS of your scene}`

[image]

3. And extend movie clip if it needed